# No response from Device SMSLib

Tags: java, sms-gateway, smslib

I am using SMSlib to send a sms to a mobile number. But the below error comes up. I have even changed the Dongles but didn't work out.

```
org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device.
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver$CharQueue.get(AModemDriver.java:535)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:338)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:313)
    at org.smslib.modem.athandler.ATHandler.getSimStatus(ATHandler.java:145)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:132)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
```

Below is my code -

```
public static void sendMessage(String number, String message) {
        Service srv = Service.getInstance();
        try {
            srv.addGateway(new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1", "COM5", 9600,
                    "huawei", "E220"));
        } catch (GatewayException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            srv.startService();
            OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(number, message);
            srv.sendMessage(msg);
            srv.stopService();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

For the debug trace you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/MR7AbRK8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Port I was using was Wrong. We have to first scan across ports by using `CommTest` Utility provided by the SMSLib. And I used a different libraries to actually send the machine.